# How to implement online edit excel on Asp.net MVC

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an excel file in the web server. I want to open the file and make some change then save it back online. What is the quickest and dirty way to do that?

In addition to that ,how to lock the excel file and notiy other person who want to edit it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the quickest way in my opinion would be to download the file onto your hard drive.  Make the changes.  And then upload it online.

To lock the excel file you need to set a password.  In excel 2003 click tools, then click options, then go to the security tab.  Enter a password so that when someone tries to open it, they are prompted to enter a password.  If they don't enter the correct one, they can't open the file.